gcc linker export variables
I use the linker to export memory location in this way (my-location-file.ld):
    ini_descriptors = .;
    *(.RxDescripSection) 
    . = ALIGN(4);
    *(.TxDescripSection)
    end_descriptors = .;

in a header I define this:
extern char ini_descriptors[];
extern char end_descriptors[];

At startup the memory gets cleaned:
memset(ini_descriptors, 0, (size_t) (end_descriptors - ini_descriptors));

Question: is it possible to export from linker the difference and put it in a variable stored in flash so to avoid the difference  "end_descriptors - ini_descriptors" ?
When I apply misra check I get errors for two reasons: memset and ptr difference. The memset can be resolved with a simple for. But I don't know how to resolve the ptr question.
